# Proof using strong induction a conjecture about $4^n$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

Compute $4^1$, $4^2$, $4^3$, $4^4$, $4^5$, $4^6$, $4^7$, and $4^8$. Make a conjecture about the units digit of $4^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Use strong mathematical induction to prove your conjecture.

Solution:

$4^1$ = $4$
$4^2$ = $16$
$4^3$ = $64$
$4^4$ = $256$
$4^5$ = $1024$
$4^6$ = $4096$
$4^7$ = $16384$
$4^8$ = $65536$

Conjecture: For $n>0$, the unit digit of $4^n$ is $4$, if $n$ is odd and is $6$, if $n$ is even.

- Basis:
  For $n = 1 \to 4^1 = 4$
  For $n = 2 \to 4^2 = 16$
  The conjecture is right for n = 1 and n = 2
- Inductive step: 
  $4^{k+1} = 4\cdot 4^k$

If $k$ is odd ($k+1$ is even), the unit digit of $4^k$ is $4$, but if we multiply a number that the unit digit is $4$ with a number that the unit digit is $6$ we get a number that the unit digit is $6$, because $4\times 4 = 16$.

If $k$ is even ($k+1$ is odd), the unit digit of $4^k$ is $6$, but if we multiply a number that the unit digit is $6$ with a number that the unit digit is $4$ we get a number that the unit digit is $4$, because $ 6\times 4 = 24$.

So, the unit digit of $4^{k+1}$ is $4$, if $n$ is odd and is $6$, if $n$ is even.

Comment: Your proof works fine.

Comment: (a) "Multiply", not "multiplicate". (b) Since your induction step goes up by $1$ every time, you only need one base case. Otherwise, it looks good.

Comment: @CarlHeckman The question asks for strong math induction so multiple base cases are appropriate

Comment: @Yeah..: Ordinary induction is just a special case of strong induction, so there is absolutely no reason to include unnecessary base cases.

Comment: @CarlHeckman I was taught as if strong was for multiple cases and ordinary was 1 case

Comment: Strong induction means that you use a result for a smaller value of $n$, but  not necessarily the previous one. I've included a proof which is by strong induction, not normal induction, below.

Comment: @Yeah.. : (See also my comment above.) This isn't the best problem to do by strong induction, because it can also be done using regular induction. A better example is the proof that a positive number can be factored into primes. (The case $n=1$ is the empty factorization. Then the inductive part is: If $n$ is prime, you're done. Otherwise, $n=ab$, for some positive integers $a$ and $b$, where both $a$ and $b$ are less than $n$. Each of $a$, $b$ can thus be factored into primes; combining these factorizations produces a prime factorization of $n$.)

Answer (score 2):

To be proven: If $n$ is a positive integer, the units digit of $4^n$ is $4$ if $n$ is odd and $6$ if $n$ is even.

Proof by strong induction: (Base cases $n=1$ and $n=2$.)

Now assume that $k\ge 3$ and the result is true for all smaller positive values of $k$. The goal is to prove the theorem for $n=k$.

Let $\ell =k-2$; note that $\ell\ge 1$.

If $k$ is odd, then $\ell$ is odd, and strong induction implies that the units digit of $4^\ell$ is $4$. Then the units digit of $4^k$ is the units digit of $4^\ell \cdot 4^2$, which is the units digit of $4 \cdot 16$, which is $4$.

If $k$ is even, then $\ell$ is even, and strong induction implies that the units digit of $4^\ell$ is $6$. Then the units digit of $4^k$ is the units digit of $4^\ell \cdot 4^2$, which is the units digit of $6 \cdot 16$, which is $6$.

Thus, we have proven that the units digit of $4^k$ is $4$ if $k$ is odd and $6$ if $k$ is even. This proves the result.